# Universal link configurations issue

Tags: swift, ios-universal-links

I'm dealing with universal link issue for the past few days and I can't understand why it's not working.

sorry can't show the domain, so I show it as `myDomain.nl`

we uploaded the `apple-app-site-association`

```
https://myDomain.nl/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

and here are the contents

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": "5LKNOW4KJS.app.appname.com",  // teamID.app bundle identifier 
      "paths": ["*"]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

And in the Xcode in the `Associated Domains` I added

```
applinks:myDomain.nl
```

The issue is simple, it will not open the app when `myDomain.nl` run on safari

I also tried to search for `swdc` the mac console on the iPhone device, but I found nothing, the logs will be completely empty after searching `swdc`

would be so appreciated if anyone help me what is the issue here.

Here are more details

I validated the AASA with [here](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/)

[image]

And

- "associated domains” capability is enabled for the app
- I tested this process both from installed app from Xcode and TestFlight
- The appID in my AASA includes two part -> `1- Team ID from Apple developer platform (see second image)` and `2- app bundle identifier from Xcode`

```
teamID.appBundleIdentifier
```

I also run in Terminal

```
martin@martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % curl --http1.1 -i https://myDomain.nl/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

HTTP/1.0 200 Found
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: application/json

{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": "5LKNOW4KJS.app.appname.com", 
      "paths": ["*"]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Rob, thank you so much. Added more details in the first post

Comment: Your AASA validation process reported a status code greater or equal to 400. You'll need to identify what went wrong there.

Comment: OK so is that probably the issue?

Comment: Yep, that certainly will prevent it from working. Try going to `https://yourdomain.no/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` with curl or a web browser and see what status code you get. You’ll want to make sure you get a clean bill of health from the validator before moving forward.

Comment: And is your `apple-app-site-association` a simple file in your `.well-known` directory with no extension?

Comment: No, it doesn't have file extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That third-party AASA validator (https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) is reporting a ≥400 status code. That will prevent the universal links from working. Try opening `https://yourdomain.nl/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` from curl or a web browser, and see precisely what status code you receive.

Until this error is resolved, universal links will not function correctly. Once you have resolved that AASA server configuration issue, if it is still not working with TestFlight (or ad hoc) archive builds, then review the rest of the configuration (e.g., the implementation of the necessary methods in the app/scene delegates, etc.).

For more information, see See [Supporting universal links in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app/) and [Universal Links for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/).

---

Once you have enabled [developer mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device/) on your device, you can diagnose universal links in “Settings” » “Developer” » “Universal links” » “Diagnostics”:

[image]

---

From your macOS console, you can also diagnose links on a device by monitoring `swcd` events from the Console app, and search for “beginning data”:

[image]

And once you see the identifier, you can see all events associated for that particular universal link:

[image]

And you can generate a [sysdiagnose](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=sysdiagnose) on your device and then look at the `swcutil_show.txt`:

```
Service:              applinks
App ID:               …
App Version:          302.0
App PI:               <LSPersistentIdentifier 0x6e68185d0> { v = 0, t = 0x8, u = 0x16c8, db = 02350E0B-B10A-4D51-9FFD-F57CA687CF17, {length = 8, bytes = 0xc816000000000000} }
Domain:               …
Patterns:             {"/":"*"}
User Approval:        unspecified
Site/Fmwk Approval:   approved
Flags:
Last Checked:         2023-01-15 19:08:53 +0000
Next Check:           2023-01-20 18:15:34 +0000
```

See https://youtu.be/xxyEq_ySoO4.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I opened it with curl, added in the first post, I received 
HTTP/1.0 200 code

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with a similar issue implementing universal links to my app a few days ago. I just got a solution after trying a bunch of things. I needed to update my path to `"paths": ["*", "/"]` in order for redirection to work - i was redirecting to a route in my domain eg. `https://www.example.com/route`.

In addition, once you've confirmed the apple-app-site-association is hosted in `well-known`, you should try

1. Deleting the app, restarting device/simulatore and reinstalling app
2. Check your entitlements have the associated domain strings added
3. Increase build version